# Save Chinese, Arabic, English etc characters in file

Tags: c#, xml, file-io, character-encoding

I have a file which contains english, chinese and arabic characters. Now when I read text of this file in a string all the text shows properly but when I again save that code to other file, it removes all my english and arabic characters and only left part is english characters.

I am using below code to read file

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("myfile1.xml"));
```

Below code I am using to write it to another file

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(myfile2.xml), content);
```

When I open myfile2.xml in visual studio it does not shows chinese and arabic characters but in myfile1.xml it does. Even if I copies content of myfile1.xml to myfile2.xml then also myfile2.xml shows all the characters.

I don't know why this is not working if I do it using the above code.

Comment: What encoding does the XML use? If it's not UTF-8, that's the problem.

Comment: So you're likely going to need to use the overload of [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to provide a specific encoding. What that encoding is, I can't be sure, but that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `UTF8` encoding when you write the file, which can handle your Chinese and Arabic characters:

```
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(myfile2.xml), content, Encoding.UTF8);
```

*From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages):*

> UTF-8 can encode any Unicode character. ... For instance Chinese and Arabic can be supported (in the same text) without special codes inserted or manual settings to switch the encoding.